# "File 'MakePri.exe' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798187 for more information"

Tags: c#, uwp, file-not-found

I keep having this error when i try to build a clean, new UWP project. Got no idea how to fix this, and the posts ive found dont really solve my problem.

What is this all about?

Comment: I found similar issue, and the reply answer told add new environment variable. For more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541821/7254781)

Comment: If your sdk does not contain MakePri.exe file, it will throw this exception, you could try to modify your target version.

Comment: Any idea where this Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets file is?